# Custom path to install NPM ,Angular and TypeScript in Windows

Tags: angular, windows, npm, path

How to forbid NPM and Angular using folder C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm in Windows?
I want to install Node.Js and Angular globally on another disk (with parameters NPM i --prefix D:\MyFolder -g).
And than I have add path to NPM, Angular and Typescript to system variable PATH

```
D:\nodejs\
D:\TypeScript\node_modules\.bin\
D:\Angular\node_modules\.bin\
```

All my project with this environment worked fine, but today I unexpectedly see message

```
npm ls -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)
```

However, Angular still present in my global folder

```
D:\Angular\node_modules\.bin>npm ls @angular/cli
Angular@ D:\Angular
`-- @angular/cli@15.1.4
```

Unfortunately, currently my global environment absolutely ignores my Node.js, Angular and Typescript, despite my PATH variables and currently environment using only default folder C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm. How to fix this issue and force Windows to use PATH variables and my global installed engine? What going wrong? All was going fine, I made a number of projects in my global environment, but today I have missing global TNS and Angular in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to forbid using folders, but I would try to ***reinstall*** it.

1st, uninstall any global packages you installed before:
`npm uninstall -g package-name`

2nd, Download Node.js from their website and install it on a different disk like D:\nodejs. Make sure to install npm globally during setup.

3 - In Powershell as a admin run `npm config set prefix D:\MyFolder` to set the npm global install prefix.

4 - Using `npm i -g @angular/cli typescript` install Angular and Typescript globaly in the new location.

5 - Update the `PATH` variable by adding these paths (separated by semicolon):
`D:\MyFolder;D:\TypeScript\node_modules\.bin;D:\Angular\node_modules\.bin`

Last, close and reopen your command prompt, and check if that works:

```
npm -v
ng --version
tsc --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Micah, but finally I found another solution. Main trouble of installation Node.JS that installer NOT CHANGED configuration file of Node.JS
So, despite I installed Node.JS to my custom directory, Node.js installer ignores that and write to node configuration file absolutely unbounded to my working environment configuration file

```
 prefix=$(APPDATA)\npm
```

This is a key of ant issues. After that any attempt to install Angular or Typescript with --prefix induce only overriding Node.JS config in absolutely wrong location.

So, You can see Node.JS config by command

```
 npm config ls -l
 ...
 ; "builtin" config from D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
 ; prefix = "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm" ; overridden by user
 ; "user" config from C:\Users\XXXXX\.npmrc
```

My solution write to D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc and D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\.npmrc and C:\Users\XXXXX\.npmrc the same line

```
 prefix=D:\nodejs
```

After that all computer has one config and than we can install Angular and Typescript to custom place

```
 npm i -g @angular/cli --prefix D:\Angular
 npm i -g --prefix D:\TypeScript typescript --save-dev
```

Also I have add to PATH variables

```
 D:\nodejs\
 D:\TypeScript\node_modules\.bin
 D:\Angular\node_modules\.bin\
```

After that all working fine again

[image: Node environment]

But I still don't understand this line on the screen

```
 Angular: undefined
```

Maybe this is because my previous project I made on Angular 15, but current version is 16